# Type R is already defined error

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]
How do I fix this? I already tried removing the R.java and cleaning the project via eclipse, but it doesn't help.

FYI I am trying to get PhotoStream from here: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/, but so far it has been very difficult to get things work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Okay..... 5 mins later google tells me the correct answer...

http://www.fairtec.at/en/it-blog-mainmenu-16/168-the-type-r-is-already-defined

I just didnt search hard enough.

> "The type R is already defined"
>
> That's the message you get in Eclipse if you try to build the Funambol Android Sync Client.
>   Reason is that you have checked two Builders that try to generate the same class.
>   You just have to uncheck the Java-Builder from Project->Properties->Builders.
>   Then the application even works fine in the Emulator.

Comment: Please accept your own answer as the correct one - it will help other people searching for an answer to see how you resolved this question.

Comment: That's really odd, that fixed it for me, but another Android project I was working on had Java builder checked.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the R.java from the src folder and rebuild the project.  This file will be automatically rebuit during this process.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.fairtec.at/en/it-blog-mainmenu-16/168-the-type-r-is-already-defined

1. click right to project click properties
2. Project->Properties->Builders.
3. unckeck java Builder
4. delete file R.java

Comment: It removes the alert, but the Java builder is required so the problem is not actually resolved

Answer (score 3):

You may want to change your package names.  It looks like you are using a 'PhotoStream'.jar which has it's R.class defined at the same package structure as you.

Here is a link to the R.java from the project on Google Code.  Notice you are using the same package:
http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/R.java?r=83

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I imported a project from work.  Turning off the Java builder as suggested in the article you found fixed my problem, but when I made code updates they were not reflected in the running app.  In my case there was an R.java in my source which I deleted and that fixed my problem.

Comment: The R in the source (why they added R to the source, who knows...) was also the problem in my case. Unchecking Java builder also helped, but I think that's not the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

as i m not using any IDE for programming but using command line Android..

i had two xml files, one in layout and other in layout-land. i was using same id "XXX" for both but while declaring i made small mistake

```
android:id="@+id/XXX" (in layout xml)
android:id="@+id/XXX " (in layout-land xml)
```

please observe extra space in second id declaration, so while creating R.java they were different and in R.java i had

```
public static final int XXX=0x7f040046;
public static final int XXX =0x7f040045;
```

which are same, so please be aware of extra spaces. Thank you