# The Type R Is Already Defined

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type R is already defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283414/type-r-is-already-defined-error)

Hey guys I have an error under R.Java. Error: The type R is already defined. I'm quite confused over this and have looked for a solution on Google but everything tells me to delete the R.Java file then build the project. The problem is whenever
I do the error just comes back.

Comment: @Merlin: Only if the fix for that question works for the OP.

Comment: @Sebastian Paaske Tørholm, @Jeff Atwood - I dispute that this is an 'exact duplicate' without the OP confirming that the other question has an answer that solves his/her problem. The `R` class in Android is notorious for being a problem particularly in Eclipse. I'm prepared to admit there is a strong chance that the answer to the other question may be the answer but I don't see that it is a 100% certainty.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have an import like this: `import com.android.R;`, if so,remove it.