# Getting error in R.java

Tags: android

I am getting error in R.java file. 
The error is
    "The type R is already Defined."
 I have tried deleting the R.java and Cleaning the project.

Comment: goto Windows >>show view >>console and tell me what is error?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283414/type-r-is-already-defined-error

Comment: +1 @Dr.nik agree with 1st comment, and post the error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step i have wrote if this situation raise ::

- dont delete it, clean it.
- goto Windows >>show view >>console and try to solve error?
- goto Project >>click `->` build automatically
- remove `import` of `R` from ***import section***
- goto layout file and check that is there any id is same name ?if yes then change it
- in layout file delete any single space,save and refresh and run.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that you have checked two Builders that try to generate the same class.
You just have to uncheck the Java-Builder from Project->Properties->Builders.

Answer (score 1):

May be there are two builders for the project.check it in project->properties->builders. I too had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chk this out: [Fairtec: Type R is already defined](http://www.fairtec.at/en/it-blog-mainmenu-16/168-the-type-r-is-already-defined)