# Create field layout/main in type R -- unable to resolve

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming and was about to run an android application. 
I got the **R.layout cannot be resolved to a variable** error. When I imported com.package.r; and deleted the android.r it didnt do anything. the error went off after i cleaned the project but then it gave an error on r.layout.activity_main (convert to activity_list...). The code snippet is attached.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.procedure.culture.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`
```

I have restarted eclipse and cleaned the project a million times, but in vain. everything in the activity_main.xml has been commented. but the error is still there. Kindly help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#A1F5F8" >

<!--
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30dp"
     />
  -->
```

Comment: Have you closed <RelativeLayout> tag?

Comment: Yes @Robert, thats closed!

Comment: Check : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm

Comment: @CSA : is `R` file generated after cleaning the project

Comment: import com.procedure.culture.R; what is that import? Have you copy-pasted a piece of code from a different source? Try removing this import if it is not related to your project

Comment: @kaushik yes it is generated after the clean

Comment: @AlexanderZhak, it is my package

Answer (score 1):

TRY the following:

```
1.check whether there are bugs in XML files.

2.Try to rebulid your application   

3.Check for any missing library files.
```

Also from your question don't import r package. Its auto generated file. Remove all imports regarding r.

Probably there may be some bugs in your XML files. Check that..

Comment: Checked for bugs. None in the XML. Done with the rebuild as well. Didn't help. :(

Comment: How do I check for the lib files?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while cleaning multiple times android loses reference to R(e.g R.id...)
Also avoid running other party's app and copy code in your created app.

Avoid `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` instead set orientation in manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching for an error on R, I read somewhere to uncheck the Java Builder. I did that but it gave me the error in this question thread. So now when I checked the Java builder, the errors have gone. Also, I was trying to add an imageview in the xml when the errors started popping. I commented it but nothing happened. Now when the errors have gone, I de-commented it but cant see the image in the application.
Anyway, thanks for your help guys! :)

Comment: It was the type R is already defined error             
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283414/type-r-is-already-defined-error